# Scroll snap CSS skipping elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll-snap

Long story short, on Chrome (81.0.4044.138) scroll snapping skips the **middle** `<div class="item2">` for some reason. On Firefox (76.0.1) it works fine. Any idea why?

```css
 html {
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    div {
      height: 100vh;
      scroll-snap-align: center;
    }
    
    .item1 {
      background-color: blue;
      font-size: 5rem;
    }
    
    .item2 {
      background-color: yellow;
      font-size: 5rem;
    }
    
    .item3 {
      background-color: red;
      font-size: 5rem;
    }
```

```html
<body class="container">
        <div class="item1">Hello World</div>
        <div class="item2">Hello World</div>
        <div class="item3">Hello World</div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a bug about it in chrome browsers *(The reason behind it, is not clear until now so no one knows why)*. So you cant apply `scroll-snap-type` to your `html` (whilst applying it to `body` won't work either) tag directly. So instead of it, **in order to make it work, you should create another `div` and wrap your element inside it.**

So try this instead:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item1">Hello World</div>
    <div class="item2">Hello World</div>
    <div class="item3">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**NOTE:** Same problem in [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/#article-header-id-5).

Comment: You can attach `scroll-snap-type` to `body`. Unfortunately, however you do it, this is unusable IRL since mobile browsers break 100vh. Scrolling on `html` is the only thing they keep stable.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Well, as you said we can use it in body, but unfortunately it does not work on Chrome browsers and its nothing about viewport or other stuff. Also in some cases attaching it to `html` will not work in safari, so it's better to attach it is other elements.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround with which I came up after quite some time tinkering.
Hope this helpes!

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.container')

// don't forget to add "scroll-behavior: smooth;" to the .container CSS

scrollContainer.onwheel = function(event) {
  // use scrollBy using the deltaY just as a direction
  // the exact value is not important because of "scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;"
  scrollContainer.scrollBy(0, event.deltaY);

  // this will stop the original scroll event.
  return false;
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item1">Hello World</div>
    <div class="item2">Hello World</div>
    <div class="item3">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **scroll-snap-stop: always;** on the child Element.